# (Mac OSX) Adding libraries to C -specifically gnuplot

Tags: c, terminal, installation, gnuplot

I am a begineer trying to get code in C. I am working on a Mac and using xcode. My only past experience has been with java using eclipse and everything was pretty straight forward. I have almost no experience with terminal.

I am required to learn a bit of C for a project I will be working on and the learning of syntax is coming along okay, but I am at a point where I need to include some libraries in my c program. Specifically I am attempting to make plots with gnuplots.

I have downloaded gnuplot-4.6.3 from their repository and I do not even know how to install the files. I have been looking around and have tried using terminal to use the ./configure command when I am in the gnuplot-4.6.3 directory. But I really don't know what I am doing so I don't even know where to go next or what to do next.

Sorry if this is so trivial, I honestly just have never done this before and I cannot find a good tutorial on what to do.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: For what it's worth, `gnuplot` is not a library.  You can't write a `C` program which includes `gnuplot.h` and then make some function calls to make a plot.  `gnuplot` is a stand-alone executable.  You'll need to write the data out to a file and then have your program write a script and call gnuplot via `popen` or `system` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using MacPorts for installing third-party tools and libraries.  It knows the dependencies required and will install them as part of the installation.

1. Download it from [macports.org](http://macports.org).
2. Install it, and allow it to modify your `~/.profile` so that `/opt/local/bin` is in your `$PATH` (any issue then just do `export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH` from the command line).
3. `sudo port selfupdate`
4. `sudo port install gnuplot`

Now that will install the library into `/opt/local/lib` with the include files in `/opt/local/include`, so now just add that library to your Xcode project.  Select the *target* and in the *Build Phases* tab open up the *Link Binary With Libraries* and press the `+` button and select *Add Other*.  Now find `/opt/local/lib/libgnuplot.a` (I am assuming that's what it's called; I don't have it installed my self):

[image]

Now add `/opt/local/include` to your *Header Search Paths* so the compiler can find the gnuplot header files.  Select the *target* and in *Build Setting* type in "header search" in the search box. Now double-click on the *Header Search Path* in the *target* column (or the project column to the right) and add `/opt/local/include`:
[image]

Comment: Your guide has been extremely useful, however I am still having problems. I do not know terminal well, so I have been following your instructions blindly. I don't know if I ever gave macports permission to set the $PATH as /opt/local/lib. I did type: export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH, before I did sudo port install gnuplot. However, when I got to the step where I was adding  the link binary with libraries, I could not find libgnuplot.a in /opt/local/lib. Was there some special step to make sure that macports sent the lib there?

Comment: What I have noticed is it installs something in /opt/local/libexec. Under there I find a gnuplot_x11 which opens a command windows and runs the following:  
'/opt/local/libexec/gnuplot/4.6/gnuplot_x11 ; exit;  
  
gnuplot: unable to open display ''  
gnuplot: X11 aborted.  
logout  
  
[Process completed]'

Answer (score 0):

It's fine! You're learning then! Keep up! When I hit this kind of problem you may want to learn about the basis for linux gcc/g++ compilation and linking processes. Then you should learn Cmake and Automake, which are basically packages to configure projects before compiling building.

A typical (good) project in Unix systems build with commands

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

or

```
cmake CMakelists.txt
make all
sudo make install
```

That's what you need to do after downloading a source tarball online to install unix programs.

Now since you are using Mac, there are so-called package installers, one which is macports and homebrew. I personally suggest homebrew than macports here (I've tried both, although macports still outnumber homebrew with the number of repos, homebrew has the newest support, especially when upgrading to a new OS). So to install homebrew you can do

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Execute that in your terminal (see http://brew.sh/) for more information.

Then you could simply install GNUplot by

```
brew install gnuplot
```